# Run a simple spark code in Scala IDE

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use Scala IDE and run spark code on Windows 7. I already installed Scala IDE and start with creating a scala project. So I need to know:

Is there any instruction to run the following code in Scala IDE:

```
/* SimpleApp.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "D:/Spark_Installation/eclipse-ws/Scala/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
                              .setMaster("spark://myhost:7077")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
  }
}
```

When I run this code I got the following errors:

```
15/03/26 11:59:55 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077/user/Master...
15/03/26 11:59:58 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077
15/03/26 11:59:58 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: myhost
15/03/26 12:00:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077/user/Master...
15/03/26 12:00:17 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077
15/03/26 12:00:17 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: myhost
15/03/26 12:00:35 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077/user/Master...
15/03/26 12:00:37 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077
15/03/26 12:00:37 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: myhost
15/03/26 12:00:55 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
15/03/26 12:00:55 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
15/03/26 12:00:55 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
```

Comment: have you tried to replace "myhost" with the actual hostname? Or "localhost"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a spark master set up? If not, Have a look at this:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/submitting-applications.html#master-urls

You would mostly want to use

```
local[*]
```

which would use each core that your local computer has, instead of using:

```
spark://myhost:7077
```

The spark:// assumes you have a spark master setup at myhost:7077

Comment: Thanks, It works for me and solves my problem. Sorry I am new (don't have enough reputation) and I can not vote your answer up :(

Comment: But what if you cannot use local[x]?  Can you post the akka config that would be required?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running as a local standalone cluster then please use local[*] that means use all the cores your machine has. So now your sparkconf object creation would look like following.`val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[*]")`